# Trying to exclude file in gruntfile config, but file path prefix is breaking expression

Tags: gruntjs, karma-runner

I am setting up grunt with a karma task that looks for all the unit test files. I need to access all `*.js` files, and `*.spec.js` files, but I want to exclude all `*.e2e.js` files. Based on the [node glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) documentation, I would expect the following to work (in karma.conf.js):

```
files: [
  'vendor/angular/angular.js',
  'vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'vendor/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
  'app/**/*.js',
  '!app/**/*.e2e.js'
],
```

However, when I try to run my `grunt test` task, it still tries to load these `e2e.js` tests, which break because each test references protractor, which karma get confused by. According to my console, I'm seeing URL's like this:

`userdirectory/repo/!app/mytest.e2e.js`

It seems that the full filepath (or at least some of it) is being preappended to the file glob pattern I supply in karma.conf.js. Is grunt doing this after the fact when it loads the karma task?

Comment: Is it not possible to place the e2e tests in a seperate folder? That way they will be easier to exclude, and include in their own configuration file.

Comment: @LudwigMagnusson Sure you could, but that doesn't help me figure out *why* this wasn't working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My problem was that karma does *not* use the same globber syntax as grunt. According to karma's [documentation](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/config/configuration-file.html), you use 'files' to show what you want to include, and `exclude` to show what you want to exclude:

```
exclude
Type: Array
Default: []
Description: List of files/patterns to exclude from loaded files.
```

Here is my fix:

```
files : [
  // libraries / vendor files needed to test souce code
  'vendor/angular/angular.js',
  'vendor/angular/angular-route.js',
  'vendor/angular/angular-mocks.js',
  'vendor/require/*.js',
  // all souce .js files, as well as all .spec.js test files
  'app/modules/**/*.js'
],
exclude : [
  // exclude all *.e2e.js end to end test files from being included
  // - Karma will break when trying to load protractor
  'app/modules/**/*.e2e.js'
]
```